# How to display XML data in XAML listbox programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, listbox

I have an XML file, each element has name of a product and it's price.

I have a XAML file with a listbox.

How do I display all the items in the XML file in the listbox programmatically in C#? Thanks.

Here is my XML file with 3 sample products:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2011-09-20T15:04:12">
<Product>
<Name>Red Chair</Name>
<Price>29.5</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>Blue Chair</Name>
<Price>27</Price>
</Product>
<Product>
<Name>Round Table</Name>
<Price>31</Price>
</Product>
</dataroot>
```

Here's my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DockPanel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Inventory" Height="350" Width="525">
 <DockPanel>

    <ListBox Name="listBox1" Margin="10" >


    </ListBox>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an XmlDataProvider (explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.aspx)). You'll need to out the provider in your Resources, speci path to get the data you want displayed, and then bind your ItemsSource to the resource